# Connecting to Trados Studio 2019 from Python

Tags: python, translation, language-translation

Does anyone know if it is possible to connect to Trados Studio 2019 using Python?

This was possible with Trados Workbench using the instructions provided in the SDL Trados 2007 Desktop SDK, but there doesn't seem to be any information online regarding whether this is possible with later versions of Trados Studio.

The current Trados Studio API documentation seems to focus on building internal plug-ins for Trados Studio rather than connecting to a running instance of Trados studio from separate code.

Specifically, I am interested in getting Trados Studio to calculate a matching rate between two Word documents.

I'm new to Trados Studio so any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the website of SDL there is documentation about using it with vb-studio to analyse files.
http://producthelp.sdl.com/SDK/ProjectAutomationApi/3.0/html/c00381ba-ae1e-4e33-acc8-61c62ed6ac47.htm

There are some tools that use Project Automation API from SDL
The SDL PowerShell Toolkit allows to script the Project Automation API:
f.e. https://github.com/EvzenP/STraSAK/tree/master
There might be something there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).